# Showing $(E(\xi))^2 \leq E(\xi^2)$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $\xi \in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,P)$ be a random variable with finite variance. Show that $$(E(\xi))^2 \leq E(\xi^2)$$

Since $$\operatorname{Var}(\xi) := E(\xi^2) - (E(\xi))^2$$ this boils down to showing $$\operatorname{Var}(\xi) \geq 0$$ which is quite restrictive. Since the lecture is not really good, I have not much of an idea what I should use. Has anyone a hint for me?

Comment: Try writing the variance using it's original definition.

Comment: what means $\mathcal L^2$?

Comment: @Masacroso The measurable functions with finite second moment (like the not quotiented version of $L^2$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $$\text{Var}(\xi)=E((\xi-E(\xi))^2)$$

is the definition of variance (at least in a number of books).

Comment: At the very least, one can verify that these definitions are equal, and with this formulation it is very easy to see why variance is nonnegative.

Comment: So we take the expectation of a non-negative function which is non-negative. So there is basically nothing to show.

Comment: @Jason Yes, you're right. And the advantage of this formulation is that it gives the intuitive meaning of what the variance is, being the square of what's close to the "mean" of how much values of $\xi$ are far away from it's mean.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek That's right. The variance is defined by this formula because it gives the intuition behind variance, see the comment right above.

Answer (score 4):

For an alternative proof, use Cauchy-Schwarz.

$$ E(\xi)^2 = \left( \int_\Omega \xi \right)^2 = \left(\int_\Omega 1.\xi  \right)^2 \leq \int_\Omega 1^2 \times \int_\Omega \xi^2 = E(\xi^2).$$

Comment: I originally suggested that using measure theory may be too advanced, but it appears the OP asked the question in the context of measure theory so this answer is appropriate after all,

Comment: Thanks! This answer I like. We already had a course on measure theory indeed and probability is the next one. But it is so basic at the moment that is ridiculous! And just bad. But it is mandatory so I guess I have no other option then learning the things on my own. Since I know measure theory I learn it that way.